# Glitchy texture from xps import

Tags: texturing, materials

So when importing this xps model the textures are imported glitchy none of the different alpha modes fix the issue.
[image]

Comment: In addition to the alpha modes, did you try "backface culling" and/or "show backface"?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Neither of those fix the issue.

Comment: Does the model look weird in solid mode too? (no textures visible)
I'd try making a new material and recreating the imported material's node tree. And if the model looks weird in solid mode too I'd clear custom split normals data and recalculate normals.

Comment: @AlexM Thank you so much! That fixed the issue the texture has been corrected.

Comment: Glad it helped :) Imported materials and models almost always require some cleaning up.